# MBCompression not minifying the webresouce.axd files

Tags: asp.net

I'm using [MBCompression](http://mbcompression.codeplex.com/) on a project and the webresource.axd files aren't minifying.  The HTML source is, can't figure why the webresource.axd is not.

The server is IIS 6.0 with ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 installed.  It also doesn't work via Cassini.  Per the readme in the source, here's what's in my web.config:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="Miron.web">
    <section name="CompressorSettings" type="Miron.Web.MbCompression.SettingsConfigSection"/>
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<Miron.web>
  <CompressorSettings reflectionAlloweded="true" daysInCahe="10" optimizeHtml="true" compressCSS="true" compressJavaScript="true" compressPage="true" compressWebResource="true" compressThirdParityScripts="true" enabled="true">
    <excludeTypes>
  <add key="" />
    </excludeTypes>
    <excludePaths>
      <add key="" />
    </excludePaths>
  </CompressorSettings>
</Miron.web>

<httpModules>
  <add name="PageCompressionModule" type="Miron.Web.MbCompression.PageCompressionModule"/>
  <add name="WebResourceCompressionModule" type="Miron.Web.MbCompression.WebResourceCompressionModule"/>
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score 0):

The author is answering my question at [Codeplex](http://mbcompression.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=63208).